# Upgrading Spring Boot Application to Latest Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have a Spring Boot project which is based on 
 `Spring Framework 4.3.7.RELEASE` and `Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE`. 
 I use the Java configuration approach. How Do I upgrade this project to the latest version of Spring Boot and Spring Framework (`Spring Boot 2.x`, `Spring Framework 5.x`)? I have checked out [this page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x), but unfortunately it was of no real help to me. Would be glad to receive any further guidance on this.

This is how my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.1.0-alpha.2'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('org.modelmapper:modelmapper:1.1.0')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile('org.modelmapper:modelmapper:1.1.0')
}
```

Comment: @dunni Thank you for the comment. I have tried to further clarify my question by adding a note that I'm using Java configuration. I've also added my current build.gradle file. HTH

Comment: @dunni Ok, I was able to switch version to latest release published on MavenCentral, 1.5.8.RELEASE. Build ok, all tests green. Good. But I was not able to switch to version 2 of Spring Boot. To me, it looks as if Spring Boot 2.x is not on MavenCentral. Any idea on how to properly set version 2 of Spring Boot in build.gradle?

Comment: @dunni Thanks a lot, that helped! Do you mind moving your comments into a separate answer so I can mark it as solution? Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first step to do an upgrade, is to just increase the version of the `spring-boot-starter-parent`. In your case with Gradle, it would the version in the property `springBootVersion`.

For Spring Boot 2 however it is important to note, that there is no final release yet, so you have to include the milestone or snapshot repositories from Spring Boot. You can find the URLs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-pom though that documentation is for Maven.

The proper settings for Gradle would look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
```